# python append array in Ordered Dicts with new values

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

My SQL Structure is like below:

```
CourseId StudentId CourseName
6001      101      Password
6002      102      Awareness
6003      101      Security
```

I'm pulling data into `tuples` using `pyodbc cursor`and creating list of ordered dicts for processing.

```
for tup in tuples:
 doc = collections.OrderedDict()
 doc['studentid'] = tup.StudentId
 doc['courses'] = [{courseid: tup.CourseId, 'coursename': tup.CourseName}]
 insArray.append(doc)
```

Now, if the student Id already exists in any of the ordered array in the `insArray` list I need to append the course details in the courses array.
For the above given records the expected `insArray` result would be:

```
[OrderedDict([('studentid', 101), ('courses', [{'courseid': 6001, 'coursename':'Password'},{'courseid': 6003, 'coursename':'security'}])]), OrderedDict([('studentid', 102), ('courses', [{'courseid': 6002, 'coursename':'Awareness'}])])]
```

Comment: can you please mention your whole required output, which will includes StudentId 102

Comment: updated the question with the exact expected insArray which contains both student id 101 & 102.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a list `insArray` as recordset you could use and OrderedDict, and then through the magic of `dict.get(key, default)` append to a previous list of courses

## Code

```
insArray = collections.OrderedDict()

for tup in tuples:
    student_id = tup.StudentId
    courses = insArray.get(student_id, collections.OrderedDict()).get('courses', list())
    courses.append({'courseid': tup.CourseId, 'coursename': tup.CourseName})  
    # list.append alters the original list and returns None

    doc = collections.OrderedDict()
    doc['studentid'] = student_id
    doc['courses'] =  courses

    insArray[student_id] = doc
```

## Result

```
OrderedDict([(101,
              OrderedDict([('studentid', 101),
                           ('courses',
                            [{'courseid': 6001, 'coursename': 'Password'},
                             {'courseid': 6003, 'coursename': 'Security'}])])),
             (102,
              OrderedDict([('studentid', 102),
                           ('courses',
                            [{'courseid': 6002,
                              'coursename': 'Awareness'}])]))])
```

## List

If you want a list as insArray, you can retrieve that with `list(insArray.values())`

Comment: I wanted all the ordered dicts in a list because pymongo has insert_many() which accepts list of ordered dicts and is much faster than the loop inserts.

Comment: [pymongo.insert_many](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=insert_many#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many) requires an `Iterable`, so you can just pass `insArray.values()`

Comment: and from what I gather from this documentation, the `document` you insert, doesn't need to be ordered, so an ordinary `dict` should suffice per student

Comment: marvelous, working like a charm and with lightning speed.